# c++ header multiple variable-pointer inclusion

Tags: c++, pointers, include, global-variables, declaration

I ran into such problem:

I have one header file:

```
//first variant:  
#ifndef LIBRARIES_H
#define LIBRARIES_H
 const char a='4';    
 #endif // LIBRARIES_H
```

I include it in few .cpp files.
 Everything works perfect.

But suddenly, if I declare a pointer:

```
//second variant:
#ifndef LIBRARIES_H
  #define LIBRARIES_H
 const char *a="asdfgh";
 #endif // LIBRARIES_H
```

please, notice,I DECLARE ONLY ONE OF THEM(of variants).
   I DECLARE a only once(I tried to change name for sadfgh or asdfg).

When I try second variant, I delete first and vise versa.

If I declare a pointer to the string I will get error "multiple inclusion of variable".
 I compile it using qt. I deleted and recompiled project a few times already. 
 [image]

Of course, I can define it in main() function, but I wonder, what is a reason of this problem?  Why cannot I declare pointer in header file and afterwards to include it in few source code files?

Comment: -1 not the real code (e.g. `cont` is not a C++ keyword).

Comment: oh, my  GOD, I just mistyped it! I am a human. how does it touch   the business?

Comment: const char * is declaring the characters constant, not the pointer.  I haven't tested it, but I'd guess it would be more likely to work with "char * const", or maybe "const char * const".  The other option is to declare it extern, and define it in a .cpp file instead.

Comment: Bryce Wagner, I don't understand you. I wrote that I can declare it silly in cpp.

Comment: @shbk: the apparent typo "touches the business" in this way: that it obviously is not the real code. Hence, *none* of the code that you provide can be trusted to be real, and if the question was just slightly more complex I would not even bother to answer, because there would be a high chance both of wasting time on helping someone who should not be helped (like helping an elderly person over the street, then she runs right back through the traffic), and of being trolled. The affectation displayed in your question is likewise a sign not to bother answering. Engineers don't think that way.

Comment: alf explained it in far more detail than I did, I was just trying to give you something quick to try, because I wasn't sure if that would work or not.  Global variables declared in a header need to have "extern", and then a single copy in a single .cpp file.  So if you couldn't get the "const" declared properly, you could always resort to treating it as an external global variable.

Comment: Cheers and hth. - Alf, I am sorry. I just typed it manually and made error. Next time I'll be more carefully. I just didn't pay attention at this. Yet once, sorry. You gave excellent explanation. Thanks you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const char a='4';
```

means

```
char const a = '4';
```

which you can read backwards as “4 is the initial value for `a` which is a constant `char`”.

Since this `a` is constant, it has **internal linkage** (i.e. it is not exposed to other translation units).

On the other hand,

```
const char *a="asdfgh";
```

means

```
char const * a = "asdfgh";
```

which you can read backwards as “"asdfgh" is an array used to initialize `a` which as a pointer to a constant `char`”.

In this case `a` itself is not `const`, and so does not get internal linkage by default: it has **external linkage**.

When you include your header in two or more translation units, you therefore get two or more global and distinct objects called `a`, which violates the *One Definition Rule* of C++ (it’s often referred to as just the **ODR**).

One cure is to make `a` itself `const`,

```
char const * const a = "asdfgh";
```

Now try to read *that* backwards, to make sense of it.

Comment: I want to add some. All my problems here grew up from internal and external linkage(as you said).  We can explicitly control it using extern(that means external variable respectivly) and static(it's not obviously, but it means that variable is internal). So, I could declare it as: static const char *s="sdf" (it's just alternative solution)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit2** Apparently, my earlier suggestion of changing

```
const char* a = "asdfgh"
```

to

```
const char[6] a= "asdfgh"
```

works.

I'm still looking into it, but when you declare a pointer, you're just saying that that pointer is constant, not the memory it's pointing to. When you declare an array, you're saying that the data behind the const is immutable as well. I'm looking into it further.

Edit3: The second paragraph of [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/4495/0) explains what's going on.

Also, "Cheers'" answer explains it well.

Comment: well, you wrote before that I should declare const char[5]="sdsfgd". you are right.  it works. But why  const char *sdf="sdfg"  doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

Cheer's answer is better than mine, but...

Try changing your declaration to:

```
extern const char * const a;
```

and then in ONE of your cpp files, say:

```
const char * a = "asdf";
```

(though if you have both consts,

```
const char * const a = "asdf";
```

should work).

You don't get static linkage unless you have both consts.  So if you use both consts, it should work, either extern or static.

Comment: believe me, I renamed it, really